# Я пытаюсь установить в проекте Unity С# версию фреймворка 4.6.1, но он возвращается к 4.7.1 после сохранения проекта

Tags: c#, unity3d, visual-studio, rider

Я использую Unity 2019.4.2f1 и Rider 2019.2.3.

Я попробовал использовать библиотеку NPOI, но она работает с фреймворком версии 4.6.1. Окей, я установил в настройках решения эту версию.

Всё хорошо, всё работает. Но стоило мне сохранить проект, как попёрли ошибки от библиотеки. Лезу в настройки решения и обнаруживаю, что фреймворк сменился опять на 4.7.1.

Окей. Я попытался проделать то же самое в Visual Studio 2019, но получил аналогичный результат.

Окей. Я попытался сменить версию фреймворка вручную в файлах Assembly-CSharp.csproj и Assembly-CSharp-Editor.csproj. Нифига. Результат тот же.

Что-то возвращает версию к 4.7.1. автоматически, и я не понимаю, что именно.

Кто-нибудь сталкивался? Есть предположения в чём проблема?

Comment: Чем же вам 4.7.1 не угодил?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ написал же: библиотека NPOI работает с 4.6.1

Comment: И? На сколько мне известно, в C# библиотеки имеют обратную совместимость, то есть версия выше всегда поддерживает все, что есть в версиях ниже. Я понимаю если бы у вас была библиотека под 4.6.1, а ваш проект под 4.0 написан, тогда да, проблемы, но 4.7.1 имеет в себе все, что есть в 4.6.1 и библиотека написанная под 4.6.1 без труда запустится на 4.7.1. Также, если я правильно понял про какую вы библиотеку говорите, если глянуть [ее страницу](https://github.com/tonyqus/npoi), то видим `4.0 and above`, то есть от 4.0 версии фреймворка и выше. Так что простите, "написал же" - мне это не понять.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Я использую этот вариант https://github.com/dotnetcore/NPOI. Пробую ещё ту, но ситуация аналогичная пока. Я не понимаю: она устанавливается - работает, после чего теряет связь с реальностью.

Comment: Ну я вам выше написал, что в .NET старые версии совместимы с новыми. Может у вас дело в другом и стоит описать подробней что не так, какие ошибки и так далее? Я конечно не знаток Unity и вряд-ли вам с этим помогу, а вот другие, если будет больше информации думаю смогут. В обычном C# проекте все именно так, я без труда могу поставить в проект написанным на . Net 4.7.1 библиотеку, которая написана на 4.0 к примеру и она будет работать без каких либо проблем.